# Save multiple copy of form - Orbeon

Tags: orbeon

Is it possible in Orbeon Form Builder to store the multiple copy of same form?

For example I have create one form with 10 fields and also I need another form with 1 more additional field. I want use the copy of existing so that I can add another field and save it.

Thanks
Pradeep Bansal

Answer (score 2):

At this point, there is no "save as…" or "create copy of this form" capability in Form Builder. You can simulate this by:

1. Opening the form you would like to make a copy of, clicking on Edit Source, copying the source of the form.
2. Creating a new form, choosing a new app name / form name, again going to Edit Source, and pasting the source you copied.
3. Pasting the source will change the app name / form name of your form to be the one of the original form, so after pasting the source, go to Metadata / Edit Metadata and reset the app name / form name.

This technique does not copy attachments you might have to your form, so if you have attachments you also need to reattach them to the target form.

Comment: Has there been any updates on this functionality? That'd be really helpful! If the form gets cloned programatically, it will cut down end user's efforts.